# Ubuntu Connects to WiFi but not Internet

Tags: wireless, 16.10

Multiple situations where I connect to a public WiFi network on Ubuntu, such as airports, schools, businesses, Boingos, TWCs, Comcasts, etc. It connects, DHCP's a correct IP address, everything looks dandy. However, no webpages load, nor any other internet services.

The reason this is an Ubuntu problem is that the same machine has no trouble in  Windows. The Boingo advertisement, or the "Welcome to guest network, press Connect to accept the terms and start browsing" or even plain old guest networks without any logins or terms to Accept required WILL NOT LOAD.

Comment: I wish I had something here to test this out on,  but maybe try installing the Chrome UA Spoofer into Google Chrome and choose something that you know is supported and maybe it will fake those public WiFi networks into thinking that you're on something else.  Just a thought.

Comment: Good thought, I'll try out my Firefox UA spoofer (don't use Chrome) next time I'm on public wifi. I'm not sure I've EVER connected to a public wifi on Ubuntu. I just whimper and reboot into Windows every time.